# How can I match any character BUT a string with POSIX Extended Regex (for sed)?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I am dealing with a string:

```
Input File
----
some**wor*ds**with**asterisks
```

By telling `sed` to match any character that is **not** an asterisk:

```
echo "some**words** **" | sed -E 's/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/FOO\1FOO/g'
```

This shall properly output: `someFOOwordsFOO **`

But this would not work with the above `Input File`.
I should therefore like to tell sed to ignore two subsequent asterisks.

```
sed -E 's/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/FOO\1FOO}/g' IF
```

would output:

```
some**wor*dsFOOwithFOOasterisks
```

Where what I should like is:

```
someFOOwor*dsFOOwith**asterisks
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? The question text is really slim on describing that. What does "any character BUT a string" even mean? Strings are strings and characters are characters, so the expression doesn't look meaningful.

Comment: @ilkkachu I think OP means replace the two `**` surrounding a word, that may have an `*` inside. `**<word with maybe an asterisk>**` `FOO<word with maybe an asterisk>FOO`.

Comment: There are so many different things you might be trying to do as the 1 line example doesn't give us enough information and the explanatory text is so vague and ambiguous, this question really isn't answerable with any level of certainty.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl with a non-greedy capturing of the word:

```bsh
$ echo 'some**wor*ds**with**asterisks' | perl -pe 's/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/FOO$1FOO/'
someFOOwor*dsFOOwith**asterisks
```

This matches from the first `**` to the next closest `**` and replaces that matching bit by `FOO`, the substring between the two `**`, and then `FOO` again.  Without the non-greedy matching, the second `**` in the expression would match the *last* such string on the line, after `with`.

Using `sed`:

```bsh
$ echo 'some**wor*ds**with**asterisks' | sed '/\*\*.*\*\*/ { s/\*\*/FOO/; s//FOO/; }'
someFOOwor*dsFOOwith**asterisks
```

This replaces the first `**` on the line with `FOO` and then the next one too, but only if the line contains `**` followed by another `**`.

Note that we don't care about what substring of the line the two `**` are flanking, only that a `**` is matched with the next closest `**`.  This goes for both commands above.

---

Looking at the example in the comments:

```
some**wor*ds**with**asterisks some**wor*ds**with**asterisks
```

This can be handled with an explicit loop in `sed` that iterates over the already given solution until there are nothing more to do:

```bsh
sed -e ':again' -e '/\*\*.*\*\*/ { s/\*\*/FOO/; s//FOO/; b again; }'
```

The Perl variant can be made to work on repeated instances of the pattern by just adding the `g` flag to the substitution:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/FOO$1FOO/g'
```

Comment: OP doesn't give further examples (maybe they will). But in case there are more complex lines, this may fail. Example for `sed`: `some**wor*ds**with**asterisks some**wor*ds**with**asterisks` will become `someFOOwor*dsFOOwith**asterisks some**wor*ds**with**asterisks`. `g` won't help: `someFOOwor*dsFOOwithFOOasterisks someFOOwor*dsFOOwithFOOasterisks`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks for the heads-up. See updated answer.

Comment: That was fast :), already gave you +1.